# Progress bar for FileField upload in a ModelForm (Django)

Tags: django, file-upload

I'm looking for some pointers to implementing a file upload progress bar that gives feedback about the current status of the upload of a FileField inside a ModelForm.

My ModelForm has got a lot of fields (not only FileField) and I would like to show a live feedback of the progress with a progress bar.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution to the problem: [django-smartfields](https://github.com/lehins/django-smartfields), this app can take care of reporting progress, convert images or videos, clean up old files and more. It has some requirements for progress reporting:

- [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)
- [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)
- [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/)
- [bootstrap3](http://getbootstrap.com/)
- [bootbox](http://bootboxjs.com/)

I am working on documentation for django-smartfields right now, but this portion of the app is still not documented, but here is how you would use it.

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from smartfields import fields

class FileModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, editable=False)
    file = fields.FileField(uploadTo='files')
    # other fields ....
    parent_field_name = 'user'

    def has_upload_permission(self, user, field_name=None):
        return user == self.user
```

Now in `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from myapp.models import FileModel
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout
from smartfields.crispy.layout import FileField

class FileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = FileModel
        fields = ('file', other fields...)

    @property
    def file_upload_url(self):
        return reverse("smartfields:upload", kwargs={
            'app_label': 'test_app',
            'model': FileModel.__name__,
            'field_name': 'file',
            'pk': self.instance.pk,
            'parent_field_name': 'user'
            'parent_pk': self.instance.user.pk
        })


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_tag = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            FileField('file', plupload_options={
                'url': self.file_upload_url,
                'filters': {
                    'max_file_size': "20mb",
                    'mime_types': [{'title': "Documents",
                                    'extensions': "pdf,doc"}]
            }}))
```

Nothing special needs to be done in the views.py, except that `'file_form'` should be in the context. Make sure `smartfields` are in `INSTALLED_APPS` and `urls` have `url(r'^smartfields/', include('smartfields.urls', namespace='smartfields')),` in them or you can create a customized upload view, by extending `smartfields.views.FielUpload`.

In the template:

```
{% load static crispy_forms_tags %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/smartfields.css' %}">

<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'bootstrap3/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'plupload/js/plupload.full.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bootbox.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/smartfields.js' %}"></script>

<form method="POST">
  {% crispy file_form %}
  <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="btn_save" value="Save">
</form>
```

Let me know if you have any questions or if it doesn't work for some reason. Make sure you use version from github, javascript file on pypi is outdated.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to achieve video compression with smart fields?

Comment: @eol Most certainly, here is a quick example I added to documentation:
http://django-smartfields.readthedocs.org/en/latest/processors.html

Comment: you are the man. does this also work with boto/storages for s3? is it currently possible within the module to compress one field multiple ways (into multiple files) while only uploading once?

Comment: It is imlemented to be independent of file storage backend, it was also tested with rackspace storage, hence it should work with s3 as well, let me know if it doesn't. It is very easy to add multiple formats to convert to, all you need is to add another FileDependency to the list of dependencies on the field.

Comment: cheers. will keep you posted. thanks for putting together a great app.

Comment: video file conversion seems to work well. although where does the progress bar / reporting come into the above example. cant seem to get that working

Comment: @eol, I'll be traveling for a few weeks, so probably won't be able to give you a better example/explanation of the process. It is a bit tricky. Just a quick outline: smartfields.js + plupload are responsible for ajax file uploading to server and retrieving progress from the server. `smartfields.views.FileUploadView` is responsible for getting the file and giving progress back to client. crispy-forms + `FileForm` from example do the form rendering.

Comment: thanks for the reply. no problem. ill keep at it and keep and eye on the docs over time. cheers and thanks again.