# File upload API: Multipart/form-data vs. raw contents in body?

Tags: http, file-upload, upload

I noticed there are (at least) two ways of uploading a file to a HTTP server via an API.

You can use `multipart/form-data` (which is what browsers do natively for file upload HTML inputs), but you can also `POST` the file content inside the request body (perhaps with the correct Content-Type request header).

What are the pros and cons of each method (in all generality, not from a browser)?

Multipart requests for instance – depending on which http or networking library you use in your programming environment (I use Node.js on the server side and Swift on the client side) – seem to be a bit more complex to create and then parse.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29659154/what-is-the-best-way-to-upload-files-in-a-modern-browser/

Comment: @vtortola not really an answer to this question. I'm not asking about any client-side networking implementations, just about the http methods.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The only difference on the protocol level is that `multipart/form-data` requests must adhere to [RFC 2388](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) while a custom typed request body can be arbitrary.

The practical implication from this is that a `multipart/form-data` request is typically larger: While clients are technically allowed to use a non-7bit `content-transfer-encoding`, base64 is used by most. The MIME headers generate additional overhead that can become a bottleneck if many small files are uploaded. Note that support for `multipart/form-data` file uploads in existing clients/libraries is far more widespread. You should always provide it as a fallback if you are not sufficiently certain about the featureset of your clients and intermediate hosts (proxy servers). Especially keep in mind that if you are designing an API for third parties that other developers will already be familiar with `multipart/form-data` and have libraries at hand to work with that.

Comment: Need an opinionated answer though, rather than "you decide based on this stuff"

Comment: If in doubt, go with `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: I'm very likely not understanding this answer. From what you said it looks like the when using multipart form data while uploading a file, browsers generally encode with base64 which isn't right AFAIK and it should be raw binary instead. The RFC link you posted says that: "the default for mail transport is the 7BIT encoding", but doesn't say anything for files

Comment: Notable that it depends where the file is coming from. If the file is always coming from a frontend UI, multipart form-data makes sense. If the file is coming from a backend server, it is unlikely to be packaged as multi-part form data.