# javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

I'm trying, as a **client**, to post a zip file to a "Restservice", using **RestEasy 3.0.19**.
This is the code:

```
public void postFileMethod(String URL)  {       
         Response response = null;              
         ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
         ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(URL); 

         MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

         FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(new File("C:/sample/sample.zip"), 
ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);              

         entityBuilder.addPart("my_file", fileBody);            
         response = target.request().post(Entity.entity(entityBuilder, 
MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA));            
}
```

The error I get is this one:

```
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request
....
Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not 
find writer for content-type multipart/form-data type: 
org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder
```

How can I solve this problem? I looked into some posts, but the code is slightly different from mine.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing two different HTTP clients [RESTEasy](https://resteasy.github.io/) and [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/quickstart.html). Here is the code which uses RESTEasy only

```
public void postFileMethod(String URL) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Response response = null;
    ResteasyClient client = new ResteasyClientBuilder().build();
    ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(URL);

    MultipartFormDataOutput mdo = new MultipartFormDataOutput();
    mdo.addFormData("my_file", new FileInputStream(new File("C:/sample/sample.zip")), MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
    GenericEntity<MultipartFormDataOutput> entity = new GenericEntity<MultipartFormDataOutput>(mdo) { };

    response = target.request().post(Entity.entity(entity,
            MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA));
}
```

You need to have resteasy-multipart-provider to have it working:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
    <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: My doubt is: I have to send a zip file, not using a form, but taking it programmaticaly from the client hard disk. Should I stil use "MultipartFormDataOutput" e "MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA"?

Comment: It depends on the server side implementation of the endpoint. If it's implemented using `multipart/form-data` then you must use `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA`. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336083/file-upload-api-multipart-form-data-vs-raw-contents-in-body)